# Can I use Arduino Nano V3 to program another arduino (Pro Mini)?

Tags: programming, arduino-nano, arduino-pro-mini, programmer

I was planning to buy serial to USB converter (FT232RL) to be able to program Arduino Pro Mini.
But the shop nearby offers Arduino Nano V3 at almost the same price.
Could I use this Arduino instead (and gain new microcontroller platform for free ;-)?

Comment: Have you tried Arduino as ISP?

Comment: I did read: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP but it says about programing bootloader and does not clarify if Nano V3 can also b used.

Comment: You can flash any sketch with Arduino ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes!**

Yes, you can substitute the Arduino Nano V3 for the Arduino Uno and follow the instructions [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP), providing that the Arduino Pro Mini is a 5V version. (Otherwise, you will have to do some voltage conversion.)

Both boards have the same SPI pins as the Arduino Uno. The connections would be as follows:

Arduino Nano --> Arduino Pro Mini
5V  ------------------->  Vcc
GND  ---------------->  GND
D10  ----------------->  RESET (10uF between RESET & GND)
D11  ----------------->  D11
D12  ----------------->  D12
D13  ----------------->  D13

The process detailed in the link can be summarized as follows:

1. Load the `ArduinoISP` sketch into the Arduino that you will use as programmer. You find it under `Examples` > `11. ArduinoISP` > `ArduinoISP`.
2. Select the serial port of the Arduino Nano (target): `Tools` > `Port` > corresponding port number.
3. Wire up the two Arduinos as described.
4. In the `Tools` menu, set the programmer to the `Arduino as ISP`.
5. Select the target board: `Tools` > `Board` > `Arduino Pro Mini`.
6. Open the program to be loaded to the Arduino Pro Mini and program it by selecting `Sketch` > `Upload using programmer`

Comment: please note, that 10uF capacitor should be connected on Nano board (programmer), instead of pro mini (target)